# Convert IBuffer to IRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

I know I can convert an `IBuffer` to a `Stream` and then from there to an `IRandomAccessStream`. But there must be a direct way.

Comment: And why must there be a direct way?

Comment: "there must be a direct way" don't bet on it, this COM stuff is really opaque by design. Unless you can simply `QueryInterface` the latter directly, you're pretty much SOL.

Comment: @DStanley Because UWP is trying to eradicate .net et al on every step of the way, as developing UWP apps has shown.

Comment: @Blindy See my previous comment.

Comment: "UWP is trying to eradicate .net " no UWP uses a superset of a subset of the full .net framework. It's not trying to get rid of it

Answer (score 6):

`IBuffer` is not a stream, so you need to have *something* to adapt one to the other. In .NET, you can use `Stream`.

```
IBuffer buffer = ...;
IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = buffer.AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
```

If it pains you to write the two function calls, you can write a helper function.

```
static IRandomAccessStream AsRandomAccessStream(this IBuffer buffer)
{
    return buffer.AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
}
```

then you can do

```
IBuffer buffer = ...;
IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = buffer.AsRandomAccessStream();
```